# Error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before '(' token 2

Tags: c++

I see this is a common error, but didn't see a response that quite fit.
I am trying to compile a simple C++ application using Dec-C++ under Win 10.
The code was included with a Chinese USB I/O module, and I need to recompile it with the prompts and comments in English.
The first part was easy, thanks to Google Translate, but the project won't compile, giving the subject error.

The errors are output when compiling an included function called from main.cpp. The offending function is below.

I would sure appreciate some help here!

Dave

```
#ifndef _MC100_H
#define _MC100_H
extern "C"{

// 2013-3-27

#ifndef WINAPI
#define WINAPI              __stdcall
#endif

#define MC100_PORTA         0
#define MC100_PORTB         1
#define MC100_PORTC         2

// Error v here, in all _declspec lines
_declspec(dllimport) int WINAPI mc100_scan_device(void);
_declspec(dllimport) int WINAPI mc100_open(int id);
_declspec(dllimport) int WINAPI mc100_close(int id);
_declspec(dllimport) int WINAPI mc100_set_pin(int id, int pin);
_declspec(dllimport) int WINAPI mc100_clear_pin(int id, int pin);
_declspec(dllimport) int WINAPI mc100_check_pin(int id, int pin);
_declspec(dllimport) int WINAPI mc100_set_push_pull(int id, int port, int value);
_declspec(dllimport) int WINAPI mc100_set_pull_up(int id, int port, int value);
_declspec(dllimport) int WINAPI mc100_read_port(int id, int port);
_declspec(dllimport) int WINAPI mc100_write_port(int id, int port, int value);
_declspec(dllimport) int WINAPI mc100_spi_send(int id, unsigned char * buffer, int length);
_declspec(dllimport) int WINAPI mc100_spi_transmit(int id, unsigned char * buffer, int length);

}
#endif
```

Comment: "The offending function is below" err.. where?

Comment: It's not very nice of you to not tell us what line the error occurred on.

Comment: Names that begin with an underscore followed by a capital letter (`_MC100_H`) and names that contain two consecutive underscores are reserved to the implementation. Don't use them.

Comment: I tried to - the 'v' in the comment line points to where the compiler states the error occurs. Not terribly clear, I suppose...

Comment: The names were taken from what was supposedly working code, unchanged. All I am doing is trying to recompile it.

Answer (score 0):

`_declspec` is the old spelling of a Microsoft extension [__declspec](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dabb5z75.aspx).  It is telling the linker that those symbols are imported from a library.  Your compiler doesn't appear to support it.  You can either edit the source to remove it, or add a define (#define _declspec(x)) either in code or on the command line to remove it.

Comment: I figured these were references to the vendor-supplied dll.
How would I remove them, or correct them with a #define?

Alternatively, would it work to edit them from _dec to __dec ?

Comment: editiing the entries from _dec to __dec got through compile, but it then failed in linker. I hadn't added the supplied mc100.lib to the project files under options, so did that. It still fails in Make, at the following line: 
 $(CPP) $(LINKOBJ) -o $(BIN) $(LIBS)
with errors like:
main.cpp:(.text+0x199): undefined reference to `__imp_mc100_write_port'